# IAM Policy for users from Group can create, delete and modify Amazon Ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have created a Group in the AWS account and also added few user to group. My requirement is that i want to allow users from specified group who can create,describe,start,stop and reboot instances. I have written below given policy for the same . But policy works for only start,stop, modify and reboot instance not for create instance. Can you help me to solve the scenario

```
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "ec2:StartInstances",
            "ec2:StopInstances",
            "ec2:RebootInstances",
            "ec2:Describe*"
         ],
         "Resource":[
            "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxx:instance/*"
         ],
         "Condition":{
            "StringEquals":{
               "ec2:ResourceTag/Owner":"Test"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `ec2:RunInstances` action.  So your policy should be:

```
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "ec2:RunInstances",
            "ec2:StartInstances",
            "ec2:StopInstances",
            "ec2:RebootInstances",
            "ec2:Describe*"
         ],
         "Resource":[
            "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxx:instance/*"
         ],
         "Condition":{
            "StringEquals":{
               "ec2:ResourceTag/Owner":"Test"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

All the EC2 actions can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazonec2.html)

Comment: You will possibly need to assign additional permissions to allow new instances to be created. This is because launching an instance involves AMIs, security groups, and possibly passing an IAM role. Plus, if users are doing it via the EC2 management console, they will need permission to list various resources (VPCs, Subnets, Roles, Security Groups). See: [Amazon EC2: Allows Launching EC2 Instances in a Specific Subnet, Programmatically and in the Console - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_ec2_instances-subnet.html)

Comment: @GreenyMcDuff Thanks for the answer. Also, after attaching this policy will it restrict users from another group with the same permissions in a different role not to modify my resources(view, delete, start,stop,terminate)?